# Error when trying to restore SQL Server 2016 backup on SQL Server 2014 with compatibility mode 110

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-backups

I'm getting an error when trying to restore a SQL Server 2016 backup on SQL Server 2014 with compatibility mode 110

> Msg 3169, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
>   The database was backed up on a server running version 13.00.4001. That version is incompatible with this server, which is running version 12.00.5532. Either restore the database on a server that supports the backup, or use a backup that is compatible with this server.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 38
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>   An error was encountered during execution of batch. Exiting.

Upgrade to SQL Server 2016 is not a option for this solution.

Comment: @downvoter I don't think asking the impossible deserves a downvote. It is still useful reference for others.

Comment: @Caltor: done - posted as a response

Answer (score 4):

You ***CANNOT*** ever restore a backup from a *newer version* of SQL Server (e.g. 2016) onto a server with an older version (e.g. SQL Server 2014) - there's no documented (or undocumented) way, no method, no workaround, no hack to achieve this - it's just not possible.

The internal database structures are just too different to provide a "backwards" compatibility path. And fiddling with the compatibility level also doesn't help, since this doesn't really change the internals of the database file - it just enables/disables certain T-SQL features.

The simplest solution is to just use the *same version* of SQL Server on all your systems. That way, you can easily back up from one machine, and restore that database onto another one.

If that isn't possible, then you must use T-SQL scripts to transport changes in structure and/or contents (data) from the newer version to the older. You can use tools like Redgate [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to help you with generating those T-SQL scripts, or you can author those scripts yourself. Or you build some other means of synchronizing the two databases with each other.

Or if you need to move "only" the data, you could check into the Import/Export wizard, and dump your data from SQL Server 2016 into an intermediate format (Access, Excel) and re-import it on the older SQL Server from there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I just need to move the data. I will run the process this way you indicated me, I will do a BCP extraction and reimport it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

You *require* an instance of SQL Server 2016 (or later) to restore a backup made with SQL Server 2016.

The compatibility version of a database is not relevant to the version of SQL Server required to restore a backup of the database.  SQL Server supports backward compatibility, so you can restore a backup made from SQL Server 2014 on SQL Server 2016, but the opposite is not and never has been supported.  No option or configuration will allow you to circumvent this limitation.

Comment: I received a recommendation about RedGate SQLBackup Tool for this situation http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-backup/support/. What is your opinion, do you had any experience or feedback about this tool?

Comment: @AlexandreBrandãoLustosa: they offer a 14-day free trial - why don't you just download a copy and give it a try ??

Comment: @AlexandreBrandãoLustosa In my experience, backup tools that work with SQL Server are still using SQL Server's `BACKUP` and `RESTORE` commands internally.  They're just sending the file to a virtual backup device interface (VDI) (i.e., using `BACKUP DATABASE [MyDatabase] TO VIRTUAL_DEVICE=....`.  Since you'd still be using SQL Server's `RESTORE` command, I imagine you'd have the exact same problem unless they claim to be modifying the database's version in the data stream or file, which strikes me as a feature that would be pretty perilous to use.

Comment: Thanks @BaconBits!!

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up a linked server or some sort of export/import as a workaround.